# Can i create an child element counter in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

Giving the following source XML,   i have processes a and b working (sources and results below)  Now, how can i get to the expected exhibit c results below ?

Extra points if it can be done in natural xslt 1.0 without resorting to a JAVA counter!

Any help is appreciated, thanks !

**Source XML  :**

```
             <A>
                <B/>
                <B/>
                <B/>
            </A>
            <A>
                <B/>
                <B/>
                <B/>
            </A>
            <A>
                <B/>
                <B/>
                <B/>
            </A>
```

**[ ex. 'a' ]**

code:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="A"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>A_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="B"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>  B_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

results:

```
A_1
    B_1
    B_2
    B_3
A_2
    B_1
    B_2
    B_3
A_3
    B_1
    B_2
    B_3
```

**[ ex. 'b' ]**

code :

```
 <xsl:for-each select="A/B"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>  B_</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

results:

```
B_1
B_2
B_3
B_4
B_5
B_6
B_7
B_8
B_9
```

**[ ex. 'c' ]**

***code:  ??????   (this is what i'm looking for)***

results (expected) :

```
A_1
    B_1
    B_2
    B_3
A_2
    B_4
    B_5
    B_6
A_3
    B_7
    B_8
    B_9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:number level="any"/>` instead of `position()`.